Xcode simulator list empty even after creating new simulator
I was trying to change my iOS deployment target in Xcode however when I check the drop down menu of my devices I only see that iOS version 17.5 is not installed rather than the list of installed iOS versions
I then went to check my list of available simulators but it was empty and nothing gets added when I try to add a new simulator to that list
I know that I have the iOS version I want installed but I can't figure out why at least that is not showing up, especially since when I actually open up the simulator via Xcode -> Open Developer Tools -> Simulator actually opens the one I am trying to target.
